# gtsummary table grouped by a column, input data from other columns

Tags: r, gtsummary

I have a dataset of ID, time, and markers. I want to use gtsummary to make a table which groups by time, and the data it is grouping are the marker columns

I want the output to look like:

```
                     Time 1              Time 2           Time 3
            mean | standard dev  mean | standard dev  mean | standard dev
Measure 1     21       2           24        2          31     4
Measure 2     41       2           26        9           1     3
Measure 3     25       1           34        2          91     1
```

So to get the summary stats like mean and standard dev, group by time, but with the measures going down the table

Code:

```
 structure(list(time = c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 
    3L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), IDs = c("ID1", "ID2", 
    "ID3", "ID4", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", 
    "ID4", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4", "ID1", "ID2", "ID3", "ID4"
    ), measure1 = c(3, 4, 5, 62, 6, 43, 6, 2, 5, 4, 2, 5, 2, 6, 5, 
    10, 7, 8, 3, 1), measure2 = c(8, 4, 5, 2, 5, 3, 23, 5, 5, 4, 
    3, 9, 10, 7, 8, 5, 3, 4, 2, 1), measure3 = c(5, 7, 3, 5, 33, 
    87, 543, 3, 10, 6, 8, 2, 9, 10, 10, 10, 4, 7, 9, 2)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
    -20L))
```

I'm not sure how to do this without reshaping the data?